# Nextjs 13 new fetching method not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

so I'm making a website using Next13 and I'm trying to retrieve specific data from my sanity client using in a dynamic route server component using the new minimalistic fetching but I get nothing, I have my console logs and looks like everything is matching up in the query but nothings gets fetched..

```
import React from 'react'
import { client } from '@/lib/sanityClient';



export default async function Page({params}) {


  const query = `*[type == "project" && _id == "${params.id}"]`;

  const project = await client.fetch(query , { cache: 'force-cache' });
  
  console.log(query);
  console.log(project)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Dummy static text</h1>
      <h1>{project.name}</h1>
      <p>{project.description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**sanity schema**

```
export default {
    name: 'project',
    title: 'Project',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'string',
        validation: (Rule) => Rule.required().max(100),
      },
      {
        name: 'description',
        title: 'Description',
        type: 'text',
        validation: (Rule) => Rule.required().max(500),
      },
      {
        name: 'images',
        title: 'Images',
        type: 'array',
        of: [
          {
            type: 'image',
            options: {
              hotspot: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        validation: (Rule) => Rule.required().min(1),
      },
    ],
  };
```

**sanity Client**

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = createClient({
    projectId: "7guc57bn",
    dataset: "production",
    apiVersion: "2022-03-25",
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_TOKEN,
    useCdn: true
  });
  
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need to see your code for `@/lib/sanityClient`

Comment: What happens if you make an api route and use the normal fetch method in a client using the `pages` directory

Comment: I just added the code, but i get the data just fine using client component fetching using useEffect for example

Comment: Are you completely sure that the generated query is the same as what you'd generate in an api route? Not just speculating, actually test it

Comment: I just realized this specific query actually does not work using a client component, trying to figure out what's wrong with this sanity query, but 100% nothing wrong with my sanity client itself

Comment: there was a typo in my query type should be _type